# Default boundary condition implementation for 1D diffusion equation equation in FiPy

Tags: python, fipy

I am trying to solve a 1D heat transfer equation using FiPy. *The documentation states that If no boundary conditions are specified on exterior faces, the default boundary condition is equivalent to a zero gradient*

If I want to apply a zero gradient to the left face should I eliminate the boundary condition code for the left face? Will the code code below automatically apply a zero constrain boundary condition for the left face?

```
# User defined Boundary Condition for the right face
valueRight = 100
phi.constrain(valueRight, mesh.facesRight)
```

This is my first time working in python and FiPy. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default boundary condition is zero *flux*. That often translates to zero gradient, but it doesn't have to and it can be misleading to assume they're the same thing.

If all you specify is

```py
valueRight = 100
phi.constrain(valueRight, mesh.facesRight)
```

then you will have a Neumann (zero flux) condition on the left and a Dirichlet (fixed value) condition on the right.